# How to explicitly override AngularJS model debouncing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

On one of the pages in our AngularJS 1.* application, I am looking at a text input<sup>1</sup> whose `debounce` is set to a value greater than zero. It is configured roughly like this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="data.value1"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 2500, blur: 0 }}"
       data-ng-change="onValueChanged()">
```

The data entered via that text input is processed when clicking a button, or when hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Now, the issue is that when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately after changing the value, the new value is not yet in the model due to the debounce setting.

The only hint towards a solution that I could find [talks about using `ngSubmit` instead of `ngClick`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8289), but we are neither using a form element nor `ngClick` (the latter at least not where it matters). The <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress is captured in a custom directive via a `keydown` event.

**Can I somehow force AngularJS to skip the debounce period and immediately update the model on my command in the handler of that `keydown` event?**

Note that an obvious workaround would be to use a `$timeout` slightly higher than the debounce delay in the `keydown` handler, so as to be sure that the model has been updated. That feels really hacky to me, though, and also conflicts with the user expectation to get some immediate reaction when hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

---

<sup>1</sup>: In fact, it's a dynamically generated UI that may contain any number of such text inputs in nested containers.

Comment: Just curious, Why are you using _debounce_ in first place? when you want to override

Comment: @Satpal: I only want to override the debounce in the specific event of a *Return* key press. The people who have developed this part of the UI insist the debounce is essential in all other situations due to various pieces of logic that are coupled to the model and changes therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I dropped the AngularJS-based `debounce` option.

Instead, I used [`_.debounce` from the lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) in any place that gets invoked upon changes to the model of my inputs. `_.debounce` provides a `flush()` method that will force the immediate invocation of the debounced function if appropriate. So, I am now calling that method when reacting to keystrokes of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to workaround the problem with a custom directive firing a 'submit' event :

```
angular.module('...')
.directive('submitListener', () =>
    ({
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.on('keyup', ($event) => {
                if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
                    console.log(`submitted !`)
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elem.val(), 'submit')
                }
            })
        },
    })
)
```

and using the directive on the input and configuring the event in the ng-model-options + debounce config :

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="data.value1"
   ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur submit', debounce: { default: 2500, blur: 0, submit: 0 }}"
   submit-listener
   data-ng-change="onValueChanged()">
```